# UTF8 characters for Javascript template

Tags: templates, javascript, character-encoding

I have a strange situation where Russian characters are outputted as garbage if the template type is JavaScript.

I.e. "Российской Федерации" is outputted correctly if the template is "Web Page", but outputted as "Ð Ð¾ÑÑÐ¸Ñ" if JavaScript is selected.

Any ideas where I might be going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

What is going wrong is character encoding. If you have the text Российской Федерации as UTF-8 encoded and this data is then misinterpreted as being windows-1252 encoding, you get Ð Ð¾ÑÑÐ¸Ð¹ÑÐºÐ¾Ð¹ Ð¤ÐµÐ´ÐµÑ€Ð°Ñ†Ð¸Ð¸. So apparently the data has been entered correctly, but the software is not interpreting it properly.

Comment: Yes! What `Content-Type` is returned in your http headers in both set ups?  Try this in terminal to check: `curl -I http://expample.com/yourscript.js`.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/919936/does-javascript-force-specific-charset

Comment: "Content-Type: text/javascript" is being returned.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but doesn't really help me :-) I know EE isn't interpreting it correctly, hence asking the question here.